# Linked queue in python can't tell if it's empty

Tags: python, class, linked-list, queue

So I built a linked queue class in python that looks like this.

```
class queue:
    class _Node:
        def __init__(self, elem, next):
            self._elem = elem
            self._next = next

    def __init__(self):
        self._rear = None
        self._front = None
        self._size = 0

    def enqueue(self, value):
        if self.isEmpty:
            self._front = self._Node(value, None)
            self._rear = self._front
            self._size += 1
            return
        self._rear._next = self._Node(value, None)
        self._rear = self._rear._next
        self._size += 1
        return

    def dequeue(self):
        retVal = self._front._elem
        self._front = self._front._next
        self._size -= 1
        if self.isEmpty:
            self._rear = None
        return retVal

    def __len__(self):
        return self._size        

    def isEmpty():
        return len(self) == 0
```

I'm using this class in order to create a really basic print queue that feeds into two printers. My problem is, my isEmpty function in the class seems to think that it is always empty. If I add 3 print jobs, then try to display them, it will only display the last one because the enqueue function thinks that the queue is empty. I just can't seem to figure out why so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The `isEmpty()` definition needs to be `def isEmpty(self):`. This is probably not your actual problem, but.

Comment: Also, you check `self.isEmpty` in `dequeue`, rather than `self.isEmpty()`. The former is just checking that the `isEmpty` method exists, rather than calling it, and will always be true. This may well be your actual problem. (Same happens in `enqueue`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are actually encountering is that you are not calling the method, but just referring to the boolean value of the method object itself, which is always true. It should be:

```
if self.isEmpty():
```